# Detect multiple windows in a process

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have been struggling with a task. I am trying to detect multiple windows in a process with the `tasklist` command.

To explain:
If you have a "notepad.exe" open and click *File → Open* you will have 2 windows within the "notepad.exe" process. (main window: "untitled - new text document" and sub window named "Open".

However, when I run `tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Open` I don't get any result.

Is there another way to detect sub windows in batch or maybe VBScript?

Comment: `tasklist` shows only the main window. It doesn't list child windows. Also I have a feeling you're asking the wrong question. Please take a step back and describe your problem (i.e. what you're trying to achieve) instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Like Ansgar said, I think you're looking at the wrong command. Unfortunately I don't generally use batch files for this function, but the SC command should be able to help. Just type SC /? in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to talk with the Windows API.

Autohotkey is pretty good at doing such things quickly and can be called from batch scripts.

It include a command called WinGet which can be used to iterate over open windows.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm

The following is an example from the documentation for iterating over all open windows.

```
; Example #2: This will visit all windows on the entire system and display info about each of them:
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
    this_id := id%A_Index%
    WinActivate, ahk_id %this_id%
    WinGetClass, this_class, ahk_id %this_id%
    WinGetTitle, this_title, ahk_id %this_id%
    MsgBox, 4, , Visiting All Windows`n%a_index% of %id%`nahk_id %this_id%`nahk_class %this_class%`n%this_title%`n`nContinue?
    IfMsgBox, NO, break
}
```